# ejs include wont pass local variable

Tags: node.js, ejs

Using nodejs and expressjs with ejs as template engine.

One of my routes uses:

```
res.render('register',{
  title: "Register",
  classname: "register",
  regdata: req.body,
  socialIcons: socialIcons,
  err: "pass"
});
```

The register.ejs file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<% console.log('In the template it gives:'); console.log(regdata) %>
<html lang="en">
  <head><% include partials/template/head.ejs %></head>

  <body class="<%= classname %>">
    <% include partials/template/header.ejs %>
    <% include partials/content/userregisterbody %>
    <% include partials/template/footer.ejs %>
    <% include partials/template/jsdefaults.ejs %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice on the second line the `console.log(regdata)`. This prints exactly what should be there to the console, which looks like:

```
{username: "jim", 
password:"abc", 
passwordConfirm: "cde",
email: "jim@jim.com",
fullName: "Jim O Tool"}
```

All going good. My problem is when I `include partials/content/userregisterbody`.

This is a longer ejs file. It should use two of the local variables, `regdata` and `err`.

In the first line of this file I have:

```
<% console.log(regdata) %>
<% console.log(err) %>
```

The output of this is:

```
undefined
'pass'
```

Why is one local variable getting passed on to the included ejs file but the other is not?? Why does regdata now come up as `undefined`? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Partials code :

```
<% console.log('But in userregisterbody:'); console.log(regdata); console.log(socialIcons); console.log(err) %>
<% if (err) { if (err === "pass") {regdata.password = ""; regdata.passwordConfirm = "";} else if (err === "user") { regdata.username = ""; } }%>
<% if (!regdata) {var regdata = new Object(); regdata.fullname = ""; regdata.password = ""; regdata.passwordconfirm =""; regdata.email=""; regdata.username = ""} %>

<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div> <!--col-->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register account for GetOutDaHouse</h2>
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputPassword">Full Name</label>
        <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" autofocus="" type="text" name="fullname" required="" placeholder="Full Name" value="<%=regdata.fullName%>" ></input>
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputPassword">Username</label>
        <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" type="text" name="username" required="" placeholder="Username"></input>
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
        <input id="inputEmail" class="form-control" type="email" name="email"  required="" placeholder="Email address"></input>
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password"></input>
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input id="inputPassword" class="form-control" type="password" name="passwordconfirm" required="" placeholder="Confirm Password"></input>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label></label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
      <p>Not a Customer? New Activity Camp? Would you like to advertise your services? Register <a href="/campregister">here</a></p>
    </div> <!--col-->
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div> <!--col-->
  </div> <!--row-->
</div> <!--container-->
```

The local object `socialIcons` gets passed fine too. It's an array of objects:

```
[
  { site: 'facebook',
    thumnail: 'facebookthumnail.jpg',
    url: 'www.facebook.com'},
  { site: 'instagram',
  ...
  }]
```

where ... should be obvious.

Comment: Can you show other partials code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Added the partials code. First line there just to see if other local objects are passed along.